# How to check for FormData using Modernizr and YesNope Javascript

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope

How do I check for FormData object using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and [YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com/)?

```
<script>
yepnope({  
  test : what.to.check,  
  yep  : 'normal.js',  
  nope : 'flashupload.js'  
});      
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking for a Modernizer way to check `FormData` the other day and couldn't find one.

However, it's easy to do without Modernizer:

```
window.FormData // exists if it exists, undefined if it doesn't!
```

So:

```
yepnope({  
  test : "FormData" in window,
  yep  : 'normal.js',  
  nope : 'flashupload.js'  
});
```

FWIW, [MDC compatability for `FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData#Browser_compatibility) says you'll be targeting:

- Chrome 7+
- Firefox 4.0
- IE 10+
- Safari 5+

... Opera support is unknown

Answer (score 4):

You can extend Modernizr with custom tests.  Just throw this into the end of your Modernizr file:

```
Modernizr.addTest('formdata', ('FormData' in window));
```